# Conda not activated in Power Shell

Tags: python, powershell, anaconda

I have already install anaconda on my Windows 10 laptop. I'm trying to activate the Python environment named `pyenv`.

First, I check the `conda env list` in my laptop, this is the output on the power shell:

```
PS C:\Users\User> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\User\Anaconda3
pyenv                    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\pyenv
```

Then I activate `pyenv`:

```
PS C:\Users\User> conda activate pyenv
```

But I check again, it still activates `base` environment:

```
PS C:\Users\User> conda env list
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\User\Anaconda3
pyenv                    C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\envs\pyenv
```

When I use the Anaconda prompt, it works normally:

```
(base) C:\Users\User>conda activate pyenv

(pyenv) C:\Users\User>
```

Does anyone know why it causes this problem and how to fix this?

**Update:**

Running `conda init powershell`:

```
PS C:\Users\User> conda init powershell
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-env-script.py
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Library\bin\conda.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\_conda_activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\rename_tmp.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\conda_hook.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\activate.bat
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\condabin\deactivate.bat
modified      C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.sh
modified      C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\etc\fish\conf.d\conda.fish
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1
modified      C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1
no change     C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\xontrib\conda.xsh
modified      C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\etc\profile.d\conda.csh
modified      C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

**Update 2:**
It works when using CMD:

```
C:\Users\User>conda activate pyenv

(pyenv) C:\Users\User>
```

Comment: When you run `conda activate pyenv`, does it throw any error or warning?

Comment: @Anwarvic no, it doesn't print anything.

Comment: what version of conda are you using?

Comment: @bug_spray `conda` version: 4.8.1. `conda-build` version: 3.17.8

Comment: You may have to close and reopen powershell after `conda init powershell`. Otherwise, maybe open an issue on github

Comment: @bug_spray It still not work. There is an issue about this that has been posted on Github, this problem exists on Windows 7.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After a while, my Powershell appear this error when I open it.

```
. : File C:\Users\User\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is
    disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at
    https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
    At line:1 char:3
    + . 'C:\Users\BinoyGhosh\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
    +   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

Then I found this [solution](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/whats-wrong-with-my-windows-powershell/f05e72f2-a429-4ee0-81fb-910c8c8a1306).

- Run Powershell as Administrator
- Run this line `set-executionpolicy remotesigned`
- Close the terminal

Then it works.

[image]

Comment: That error stats appearing after you run the command: `conda init powershell`

Comment: @AgustinBarrachina Yes, it appears after I run that command.

Comment: Make sure to restart the terminal. Then run conda activate...

Answer (score 1):

The above solution did not fully work for me. I had to additionally run:

```
conda init powershell
```

After restarting the powershell, it was possible to run:

```
conda activate myenv
```

successfully.