# Running Anaconda tesorflow-gpu on Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, powershell, tensorflow, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I have a conda environment (`tf-2-gpu`) that has TensorFlow GPU installed. If I used Anaconda prompt or CMD it works like charm.

However, in Visual Studio code I have the following message:

```
> conda activate tf-2-gpu
> & C:/Users/<my_user>/.conda/envs/tf-2-gpu/python.exe my_python_script.py
2020-11-16 15:01:07.297343: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
```

Anaconda seems to be working because it activates it correctly and also at first I had some import errors and then I install the libraries on the conda env and started working.

Obviously, I have the GPU, and as I said before if I run this on cmd it works.

This seems to be a problem with PowerShell, any idea here?

---

I found that the dll file is inside `.conda/env/tf-2-gpu/Library/bin` I added it to the environment path but it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 solutions I found so far. But both of them are not still perfect and have a problem.

**Option 1:**
This option is the solution found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62082873/conda-not-activate-in-power-shell).
Run PowerShell as admin and then:

```
conda init powershell
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
```

This is bad because you must change the execution policy that may have security risks.

If you only run the first command you will have this message and the code will still not be working.

```
. : File C:\Users\<my_user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:3
+ . 'C:\Users\<my_user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1'
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
Loading personal and system profiles took 4461ms.
```

Using `powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\Users\<my_user>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1` doesn't work for me I don't know why.

**Option 2:**
Set CMD as default shell.

This means it is still not working in PowerShell.

Answer (score -1):

**Following Steps worked for me:**

Do the same as in the video.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r31jnE7pR-g

Also install tensorflow estimator which is missing in the video. In picture you can see my environment which is working for me.

[my environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpggv.png)

Maybe you have to change the versions to the same ones.
Now go in Visual Code and run your code with the anaconda environment you created before. See picture below.

[select your environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjPSk.png)

In my case it it tf_env, what i created and named.

Try to run your code. If Visual Code says something is missing try to install it with the anaconda terminal. Click the "play"-Button to start the terminal.

[play Button terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjruh.png)

Also close and open Visual Code when you do changes, sometimes anaconda too. Now try this code below.

```
print("Num GPU: ", len(tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU")))

print(tf.test.is_gpu_available()) 
print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())



> OUTPUT 
> Num GPU:  1 
> WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-2-8748de971110>:3:
> is_gpu_available (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is
> deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Instructions for
> updating: Use `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead. 
> True
> True
```

If your output is the same, everything went fine. Now when you train a model you should see your gpu running in your task manager.

Hopefully it helps you guys :)